# Decoding nested JSON structures

Tags: json, elm

I'm trying playing with the source code of [elmplayground](https://github.com/jackfranklin/elmplayground) and I'm trying to create a configuration json file for the blog. The issue I'm having at this point is that I don't know how I can decode a post/page author as a nested structure. What I want is that the `author` field in posts and pages do a reference to an author in the `config.json`.

config.json:

```
{
  "posts": [{
    "slug": "/hello-world",
    "title": "Hello World",
    "name": "hello-world",
    "publishedDate": "2016-10-30",
    "author": "Gabriel",
    "intro": ""
  }],
  "pages": [{
    "slug": "/hello",
    "name": "index",
    "title": "Elm Playground",
    "publishedDate": "2016-09-01",
    "author": "Gabriel",
    "intro": ""
  }],
  "authors": {
    "Gabriel": {
      "name": "Gabriel Perales",
      "avatar": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

Type Content for pages and posts:

```
type alias Content =
    { title : String
    , name : String
    , slug : String
    , publishedDate : Date
    , author : Author
    , markdown : WebData String
    , contentType : ContentType
    , intro : String
    }
```

Type Author:

```
type alias Author =
    { name : String
    , avatar : String
    }
```

Currently this is my config decoder:

```
configDecoder : Decoder Config
configDecoder =
    Decode.map2 Config
        (field "posts" <| Decode.list <| decodeContent Post)
        (field "pages" <| Decode.list <| decodeContent Page)

decodeContent : ContentType -> Decoder Content
decodeContent contentType =
    Decode.map8 Content
        (field "slug" string)
        (field "name" string)
        (field "title" string)
        (field "publishedDate" decodeDate)
        (field "author"
            (string
                -- I want to decode the author from "authors"
                -- I have tried with 
                -- (\name -> at ["authors", name] decodeCofigAuthor) but it doesn\'t work
                |> andThen (\name -> Decode.succeed <| Author name "...")
            )
        )
        (Decode.succeed RemoteData.NotAsked)
        (Decode.succeed contentType)
        (field "intro" string)


decodeConfigAuthor : Decoder Author
decodeConfigAuthor =
    Decode.map2 Author
        (field "name" string)
        (field "avatar" string)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by decoding the authors, and then use `andThen` to pass the authors `Dict` into `decodeContent`.  You can then use `Decode.map` to convert to author name into a lookup in the `authors` `Dict`.

```
decoder =
    (field "authors" <| Decode.dict <| authorDecoder)
        |> Decode.andThen configDecoder

configDecoder authors =
    Decode.map2 Config
        (field "posts" <| Decode.list <| decodeContent Post authors)
        (field "pages" <| Decode.list <| decodeContent Page authors)

decodeContent contentType authors =
    Decode.map8 Content
        -- …
        (field "author" (string |> Decode.map (\name -> Dict.get name authors)))
        -- …
```

This would change your model to use a `Maybe Author`, but you could also use `Decode.andThen` and return a `Decode.fail` if `Dict.get` returns `Nothing`.

Comment: I'm going to try it, but it looks like what I was looking for